# How to forward a message from Azure estate to NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm creating an IoT solution. On my web app i want to have a table on the dashboard that updates alert events in realtime.

I currently have an API, written in NodeJS that receives the JSON and invokes sockets.io to update the table. This solution seems a bit clunky. 
I'm wondering is there a more seamless way to do this, similar to how the different components within azure link together.

I've looked into Azure Queues and having nodeJS subscribe and consume from the queue but as far as I could find there's no way to persist a queue connection from NodeJS and I would have had to continually poll.

I've looked into Power BI as well but I need to be able to completely change and modify every aspect of the design too.

The following is what I have so far:

Devices send data to IoT Hub. This is then processed by an azure stream analytics job and if a certain criteria is hit it sends the message to a documentDB for storage, and also to a service bus queue. I have a logic app which is triggered by a message arriving on the service bus queue and then POSTs the data to my API.

Comment: Hi, 
What about using Azure functions? You can trigger event based on your Service Bus queue, and then call other Azure services or trigger your API. Here's a list of possible input and output for functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings

Comment: Thanks for your response. While not quite what I had in mind initially, I decided to go ahead with my setup as I had it. I did however use an azure function to clean up the data from the service bus queue before triggering my API. works quite well in the end